# R installation file for SLES 11 SP 3

Tags: r, linux, sles

I am trying to get R installed on a SLES 11 SP3 machine, unfortunately I cannot upgrade to newer versions of SLES and I cannot make use of yast or zipper. So I have been looking for the installation file of R that was available when SLES 11 SP3 was release with no luck. Does anyone know where I can get this from? Or does anyone know if I can use precompiled binaries and where they might be?

I tried using the latest version of R, but there are so many dependencies required that my installation keeps failing requesting all the dependencies.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274312/installing-r-cannot-find-repo-for-sle-11-sp3

Comment: Compiled binaries very unlikely. Provide a range of dates.

Comment: Apparently the asker in that identical thread on unix.stackexchange.com found a binary. I left a comment asking him or her to provide the link. You may want to do the same.

Comment: i was going to message the person on that link directly, but i could not find a way to do so. It must exist somewhere, but i cannot seem to find it.